# Linguistic search features filter search results

Tags: 2013, search-results, document, language

we handle a lot of documents in different languages. Trying to search for documents and getting no results we've come up to [linguistic-search-features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/linguistic-search-features) saying

> SharePoint Server use several linguistic features to help improve search relevance

Does this mean that

- Search results are always(!) related to my user profile? (and the languages which are assigned to)
- There is no way to simply deactivate this and search really for "all documents"?

Answer (score 0):

search request

```
CustomSiteID:{GUID} AND ListID:{GUID} AND WebId:GUID AND ListItemID:ID
```

works for all documents without culture restriction (= using default culture)